# how to get jquery.couch.app.js to work with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, couchapp

I have tested this on Windows XP SP3 in IE7 and IE8 ( in all compatibility modes ) and Windows 7 Ultimate in IE8 (in all compatiblity modes) and it fails the same way on both. I am running the latest HEAD from the the [couchapp](http://github.com/couchapp/couchapp) repository. This works fine on my OSX 10.6.3 development machine. I have tested with Chrome 4.1.249.1064 (45376) and Firefox 3.6 on Windows 7 Ultimate and they both work fine. As do both Safari 4 and Firefox 3.6 on OSX 10.6.3

Here is the error message

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;
>   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0) Timestamp: Wed, 28 Apr
>   2010 03:32:55 UTC
>
> Message: Object doesn't support this
>   property or method Line: 159 Char: 7
>   Code: 0 URI:
>   http://192.168.0.105:5984/test/_design/test/vendor/couchapp/jquery.couch.app.js

and here is the "offending" bit of code, which works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari just fine. If says the failure is on the line that starts `qs.forEach()` from the file [jquery.couch.app.js](http://github.com/couchapp/couchapp/blob/master/vendor/_attachments/jquery.couch.app.js)

```
  157 var qs = document.location.search.replace(/^\?/,'').split('&');
  158 var q = {};
  159 qs.forEach(function(param) {
  160   var ps = param.split('=');
  161   var k = decodeURIComponent(ps[0]);
  162   var v = decodeURIComponent(ps[1]);
  163    if (["startkey", "endkey", "key"].indexOf(k) != -1) {
  164     q[k] = JSON.parse(v);
  165   } else {
  166    q[k] = v;
  167   }
  168 });
```

Comment: Doesn't work in IE... *now where have I heard that before...?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

forEach() is a function that's recently added to the JavaScript specification, so not all browsers support it.

You can read about it at MDC:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Under "Compatibility", you'll find a snippet that makes forEach() available.

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}
```

So, copy and paste the code above to your script and forEach() should work.

Comment: this only partially fixed my problem as I had to add `indexOf` as mentioned in my answer to this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to add `indexOf()` to the Array object to get it working after fixing the forEach() problem

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt)
    {
        var len = this.length >>> 0;

        var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
        from = (from < 0)
                ? Math.ceil(from)
                : Math.floor(from);
        if (from < 0)
            from += len;

        for (; from < len; from++)
        {
            if (from in this &&
                this[from] === elt)
                return from;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```